# Taking children to the musical Kinky Boots

Tags: teen, age-appropriate, middle-childhood, media

Our local theater is back live this fall. I have tickets for our family, and want to decide whether it is appropriate for 9 and 13 year old children. What kinds of mature topics does Kinky Boots have?  What other information might I want to consider in making this decision?

Comment: Hi! Welcome to Parenting.  We don't consider opinion-based topics to be appropriate for this site, but we do consider things like what you ask okay - just adjusted slightly to be answerable in a factual way. I've edited your question to be on topic.  Please review our [faq] and the [help] for more information on what's on topic here, and feel free to improve my edits if you feel I missed anything important.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you consider appropriate will be a personal decision, but [Common Sense Media reviews for the movie based on the musical](https://www.commonsensemedia.org/movie-reviews/kinky-boots) consider it appropriate for 14+ (by the website itself) or 10+/11+ (by parents/kids).  They specifically mention low to moderate levels of violence, bad language, sex, and drinking/drug use/smoking.  They also mention it's quite long.  There is one specific number ("Red is Sex") that might be a good place to start - look up the words or a video of someone doing the piece and see if that meets your standards; that seems to be the most objectionable piece to most reviewers.  No actual sex is on stage/screen (in the movie, of course each portrayal of a given musical can make changes here!).

The musical's themes in particular can be challenging for children who have not been exposed to transgender/transsexual/transvestite topics, though of course the movie is very trans-positive.  If your children have little to no awareness of these topics, it might be worth having a discussion first about what the differences are between these three, plus what a "drag queen" is and how that is different.

Comment: +1 for adding "having a discussion". Most sensitive topics are only bad for children if they aren't able to place it and/or learn when it is appropriate (if at all) to do those things themselves.